# How to make antlr3 parsing "forward?"

Tags: java, antlr, antlr3

I'm trying to parse the following grammar with Antlr3:

```
String...
java.lang.String
java.lang.Object...
```

This is my `.g` file (part of it):

```
doc: name DOTS? EOF;
name: ATOM ('.' ATOM)*;
ATOM: ('a' .. 'z' | 'A' .. 'Z')+;
DOTS: '...';
```

It doesn't work. Antlr3 treats `'.'` after `ATOM` as part of `name`, not the beginning of `DOTS`. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

When I use your grammar:

```
grammar T;

parse : doc+  EOF;
doc   : name DOTS?;
name  : ATOM ('.' ATOM)*;
ATOM  : ('a' .. 'z' | 'A' .. 'Z')+;
DOTS  : '...';
WS    : (' ' | '\n') {skip();};
```

to parse the source:

```
String...
java.lang.String
java.lang.Object...
```

I get the  following parse tree:
[image]

So, I'm not sure what the problem is exactly: it seems to do what you want.

Comment: looks like you're right.. I need to investigate more. Btw, how did you produce this graph? What is the tool?

Comment: @yegor, I did that in [ANTLRWorks](http://www.antlr.org/works/index.html): there's an interpreter-tab at the lower part of the windows. Note that it only works with the simplest of grammars. When predicates come into play, the interpreter does not works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this be OK? I'm sure there are better ways of representing your required grammar. I assume would like to match any number of dots after the last ATOM as dots.

```
doc:    
     name dots EOF;

name: ATOM (DOT ATOM)*;

dots    :   
    DOT*;

DOT :   '.';
ATOM: ('a' .. 'z' | 'A' .. 'Z')+;
```

Comment: @yegor256, it works for me on AntlrWorks 1.4.2 - you do have dots in lowecase?

Comment: I was just about to write something like that - the grammar stops the dots attaching themselves to the name, but fails on multiline files.